# X3: Linker Error (unresolved external symbol "parse_rule") on nonterminal parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

First of all I am using MSVC 2017 (latest version).
Here is my code for the nonterminal parser:

player.hpp

```
namespace parse
{
    namespace impl
    {
        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

        struct _tag;

        using player_type = x3::rule<_tag, PlayerIterator>;
        using player_vector_type = x3::rule<_tag, std::vector<PlayerIterator>>;
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE(player_type);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE(player_vector_type);
    }; //impl

    impl::player_type player();
    impl::player_vector_type player_vector();
}; //parse
```

player.cpp

```
namespace parse
{
    namespace impl
    {
        const player_type player = "player";
        const player_vector_type player_vector = "player_vector";
        auto player_find = [](auto &ctx)
        {
            auto &attr = x3::_attr(ctx);
            if(attr.which() == 0)
                return x3::_val(ctx) = PlayerManager::find(boost::get<int>(attr));
            return x3::_val(ctx) = PlayerManager::find(boost::get<std::string>(attr));
        };
        auto player_vector_find = [](auto &ctx)
        {
            return x3::_val(ctx) = PlayerManager::vector_find(x3::_attr(ctx));
        };
        auto const player_def = (x3::int_ | (+x3::char_))[player_find];
        auto const player_vector_def = (((+x3::char_)[player_vector_find]));
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(player);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(player_vector);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE(player_type, iterator_type, context_type);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE(player_vector_type, iterator_type, context_type);
    } //impl
    parse::impl::player_type player() { return impl::player; }
    parse::impl::player_vector_type player_vector() { return impl::player_vector; }
}//parse
```

I get linker LNK2019 errors about "unresolved external symbols referenced":
 [Pastebin.com link with the errors](https://pastebin.com/HcYnaFyi)
Any ideas about them?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
That's how I call it in my source file:

```
void test(std::string &params)
{
    std::tuple<PlayerIterator, std::vector<PlayerIterator>, std::string> tuple;
    if (!x3::phrase_parse(params.begin(), params.end(), parse::player()>> parse::player_vector() >> (+x3::char_), x3::space,tuple))
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Parsing failed" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Parsing succeded" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Found player, size of player vector: "<< std::get<1>(tuple).size() << ", also parsed string:" << std::get<2>(tuple);
    return;
};
```

Comment: You've pasted irrelevant code.

Comment: As with all unresolved external, did you add the library to the project, either in the project settings or as a `#pragma comment(lib, "LibraryName.lib")` instruction?

Comment: @MartinVéronneau what library? [boost::spirit::x3](https://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/index.html) is header only...

Comment: An unresolve external means that the compiler found a definition for a function, but the linker didn't find any implementation of it. I never used x3, so I can't tell exactly what's going on. That's why I only commented. The linker seems to indicate the missing function is called from boost::spirit::x3::rule(), so it's probably a rule definition that is wrong (if I understand the purpose of x3 correctly).

Comment: @MartinVéronneau I know it can't find it, that's why I posted. Actually the macro `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE` should make the definition of the function `parse::impl::parse_rule<>()`. See it [on Spirit's GitHub repo](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/b4c5ef702bf6c28e964a84c9e9abe1a6549bce69/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp#L169)

Comment: Well... The examples I'm seeing online don't look like what you did. Did you try posting to their forums?

Comment: To all interested (@MartinVéronneau) the go-to resource here is this page: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials/minimal.html. See also my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm willing to bet $10 that you mismatched the context or iterator types on the instantiations.

E.g. in your `test` function, the argument is `std::string&`, hence `params.begin()` will be `std::string::iterator`. If you had the `iterator_type` configured as follows:

```
using iterator_type = std::string::const_iterator; // very sensible!
```

you would have unresolved externals because the iterator type doesn't match the one actually required.

Same thing for the context. To match your invocation it needs to be exactly:

```
using context_type = x3::phrase_parse_context<x3::space_type>::type;
```

Sadly you didn't show the whole code, so you'll have to check on your own.

### Notes

1. re-using the tag type is recipe for disaster. I don't think it *can* work. The rule tags are what dispatches the implementation function in the case of separated compilation units. Fix it:

   ```
   using player_type        = x3::rule<struct player_tag,        PlayerIterator>;
   using player_vector_type = x3::rule<struct player_vector_tag, std::vector<PlayerIterator>>;
   ```
2. copying the rules seems wasteful, consider returning by reference:

   impl::player_type const& player();
      impl::player_vector_type const& player_vector();

   Note: this should be fine w.r.t. [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors)
3. using `which()` on a variant is an anti-pattern. You can replace

   ```
   auto player_find = [](auto &ctx) {
       auto &attr = x3::_attr(ctx);
       if (attr.which() == 0)
           return x3::_val(ctx) = PlayerManager::find(boost::get<int>(attr));
       return x3::_val(ctx) = PlayerManager::find(boost::get<std::string>(attr));
   };
   ```

   With

   ```
   auto find = [](auto const& key) { return PlayerManager::find(key); };
   auto player_find = [](auto &ctx) {
       return x3::_val(ctx) = boost::apply_visitor(find, x3::_attr(ctx));
   };
   ```
4. `(+x3::char_)` always matches all input
5. `(+x3::graph)` still matches all input because of the skipper
6. Instead you wanted a lexeme:

   ```
   auto const name              = x3::lexeme[+x3::graph];
   auto const player_def        = (x3::int_ | name) [player_find];
   auto const player_vector_def = name[ player_vector_find];
   ```
7. May I suggest to write the `test` function a lot more concisely:

   ```
   void test(std::string const &params) {
       auto comment_ = x3::lexeme[+x3::char_];

       PlayerIterator player;
       PlayerIterators vec;
       std::string comment;
       auto tuple = std::tie(player, vec, comment);

       if (phrase_parse(params.cbegin(), params.cend(), parse::player() >> parse::player_vector() >> comment_, x3::space, tuple)) {
           std::cout << "Parsing succeded" << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Found player, size of player vector: " << vec.size() << "\n";
           std::cout << "Also parsed string: " << std::quoted(comment);
       } else {
           std::cout << "Error: Parsing failed" << std::endl;
       }
   }
   ```

### Full Demo

See it **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8gcrM81P2NDSbJts)</kbd>**

- #### stuff.h

  Contains mockup `PlayerManager`

  ```
  #pragma once
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>

  struct PlayerIterator { };
  using PlayerIterators = std::vector<PlayerIterator>;

  struct PlayerManager {
      static PlayerIterator              find(std::string const&)        { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return {}; } 
      static PlayerIterator              find(int)                       { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return {}; } 
      static PlayerIterators vector_find(std::string const&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return {}; } 
  };
  ```
- #### test.h

  ```
  #pragma once
  #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
  #include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
  #include "stuff.h"

  namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

  namespace parse
  {
      namespace impl
      {
          using player_type        = x3::rule<struct player_tag,        PlayerIterator>;
          using player_vector_type = x3::rule<struct player_vector_tag, PlayerIterators>;

          BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE(player_type)
          BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE(player_vector_type)
      } //impl

      impl::player_type const& player();
      impl::player_vector_type const& player_vector();
  } //parse
  ```
- #### test.cpp

  ```
  #include "stuff.h"
  #include "test.h"

  using iterator_type = std::string::const_iterator;
  using context_type = x3::phrase_parse_context<x3::space_type>::type;

  namespace parse {
      namespace impl {
          const player_type player               = "player";
          const player_vector_type player_vector = "player_vector";

          auto find               = [](auto const& key) { return PlayerManager::find(key); } ;
          auto player_find        = [](auto &ctx)       { return x3::_val(ctx) = boost::apply_visitor(find, x3::_attr(ctx)); } ;
          auto player_vector_find = [](auto &ctx)       { return x3::_val(ctx) = PlayerManager::vector_find(x3::_attr(ctx)); } ;

          auto const name              = x3::lexeme[+x3::graph];
          auto const player_def        = (x3::int_ | name) [player_find];
          auto const player_vector_def = name[ player_vector_find];

          BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(player)
          BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(player_vector)

          BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE(player_type,        iterator_type, context_type)
          BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE(player_vector_type, iterator_type, context_type)
      } // namespace impl

      parse::impl::player_type const& player()               { return impl::player; }
      parse::impl::player_vector_type const& player_vector() { return impl::player_vector; }
  } // namespace parse
  ```
- #### main.cpp

  ```
  #include "stuff.h"
  #include "test.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>

  void test(std::string const &params) {
      auto comment_ = x3::lexeme[+x3::char_];

      PlayerIterator player;
      PlayerIterators vec;
      std::string comment;
      auto tuple = std::tie(player, vec, comment);

      if (phrase_parse(params.cbegin(), params.cend(), parse::player() >> parse::player_vector() >> comment_, x3::space, tuple)) {
          std::cout << "Parsing succeded" << std::endl;
          std::cout << "Found player, size of player vector: " << vec.size() << "\n";
          std::cout << "Also parsed string: " << std::quoted(comment);
      } else {
          std::cout << "Error: Parsing failed" << std::endl;
      }
  }

  int main() {
      test("42 someword # bogus trailing comment");
  }
  ```

Prints:

```
static PlayerIterator PlayerManager::find(int)
static PlayerIterators PlayerManager::vector_find(const std::string &)
Parsing succeded
Found player, size of player vector: 0
Also parsed string: "# bogus trailing comment"
```

Comment: Added demo [Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8gcrM81P2NDSbJts)